# Ejabberd Server Processor Overload (CPU Overload)

Tags: erlang, load-balancing, ejabberd

We have enabled the clustering in the 2 Ejabberd servers. But still we are getting the CPU overload alert after 78 sessions (around 156 users) connected to Ejabberd and server went to hung status.

Since we are getting the alert after around 150+ users connected, what are all the possible resources we can increase at hardware level (like memory, processor, etc.,) to resolve this issue?

Ejabberd Version: 17.01
CPU Count: 4 (each server)
Memory: 8GB (each server)

Comment: i think that there are some issues in configuration or behavior of conntected users.

Comment: could you resolve the problem? what was the problem? what was the solution?

Answer (score 1):

You get CPU overload with just 78 clients connected in each node? Obviously there is something weird there!

Are the clients just connected, or are they sending many messages?

Do the accounts have a small roster, or do they have thousands of contacts?

What happens if only one node is used, not in cluster: does it handle many more accounts, or it overloads CPU like in cluster?

Comment: All the clients will be connected and they will interact with many messages. Basically our application is helping to interact between tutor and student through canvas whiteboard.

Small roster means, I am not getting this point?

One room will be created for each tutor and student and they both will interact. Like that multiple tutor and their corresponding students will be connected and they will interact.

With the single node also we are getting same CPU overload issue.

Comment: So there are few users with few contacts, but send many messages. If server works correctly when they are silent (not sharing whiteboard), and overloads when several are using the whiteboard, then you get some clue of where may be the problem. You can try to sniff a client's traffic when sharing the whiteboard, to make an idea of how many messages are they sending (for example one per second, or much more traffic?).

Comment: @Badlop and what is the solution if the problem is the clients are sending many messages?